# Subtotals and Grand totals across two axis

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Industry   Firm          Project   Month       Cost
0  Auto       Company 1     NUKDJF    06-2020     1000.00
1  Auto       Company 1     NUKDJF    07-2020     5000.00     
2  Auto       Company 1     NUKDJF    08-2020     5000.00
0  Auto       Company 1     Alpha     06-2020     3000.00
1  Auto       Company 1     Alpha     07-2020     0.00
2  Auto       Company 1     Alpha     08-2020     0.00
3  Lamps      ASDF Inc.     BigThing  06-2020     2000.00
4  Lamps      ASDF Inc.     BigThing  07-2020     500.00     
5  Lamps      ASDF Inc.     BigThing  08-2020     500.00
7  Lamps      Super Corp    SupProj   06-2020     1500.00
8  Lamps      Super Corp    SupProj   07-2020     8000.00
9  Lamps      Super Corp    SupProj   08-2020     9000.00
```

and I want to turn it into an Excel-style Pivot table with Subtotals and Grand Total like this:

```
Industry    Firm            Project        06-2020     07-2020     08-2020     Total
Auto                                       4000.00     5000.00     5000.00     14000.00
            Company 1                      4000.00     5000.00     5000.00     14000.00
                            NUKDJF         1000.00     5000.00     5000.00     11000.00
                            Alpha          3000.00        0.00        0.00      3000.00
Lamps                                      3500.00     8500.00     9500.00     21500.00
            ASDF Inc.                      2000.00      500.00      500.00      3000.00
                            BigThing       2000.00      500.00      500.00      3000.00
            Super Corp                     1500.00     8000.00     9000.00     18500.00
                            SupProj        1500.00     8000.00     9000.00     18500.00
Total                                      7500.00    13500.00    14500.00     35500.00
```

I am currently at this stage:

```py
    pd.concat([
        df.assign(
            **{x: 'total' for x in ['Industry', 'Firm', 'Project', 'Month'][i:]}
        ).groupby(list(['Industry', 'Firm', 'Project', 'Month'])).sum() for i in range(5)
    ]).sort_index()
```

but this does not provide Totals per Month

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly not elegant, but works...

```
indices = ["Industry","Firm","Project"]
l = list()
for index in [indices[0],indices[0:2],indices,None]:
    tmp = pd.pivot_table(df,values="Cost",index=index,columns=["Month"],aggfunc=np.sum)
    tmp["Total"] = tmp.sum(axis=1)
    tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)
    for col in indices:
        if col not in tmp.columns:
            tmp[col] = ""
    tmp.set_index(indices,inplace=True)
    tmp.drop("index",axis=1,errors='ignore',inplace=True)
    l.append(tmp)

l[-1].index = [("Total","","")]
output = pd.concat(l[:-1]).sort_index()
output = pd.concat([output,l[-1]])
```

output

```
Month                         06-2020  07-2020  08-2020    Total
Industry Firm       Project                                     
Auto                           4000.0   5000.0   5000.0  14000.0
         Company 1             4000.0   5000.0   5000.0  14000.0
                    Alpha      3000.0      0.0      0.0   3000.0
                    NUKDJF     1000.0   5000.0   5000.0  11000.0
Lamps                          3500.0   8500.0   9500.0  21500.0
         ASDF Inc.             2000.0    500.0    500.0   3000.0
                    BigThing   2000.0    500.0    500.0   3000.0
         Super Corp            1500.0   8000.0   9000.0  18500.0
                    SupProj    1500.0   8000.0   9000.0  18500.0
Total                          7500.0  13500.0  14500.0  35500.0
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks alot. It cannot always be elegant...

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `groupby` and `pivot_table`

```py
df_t = df.groupby(['Industry', 'Firm', 'Project']).agg({'Cost':'sum'}).reset_index()
df_t['Month'] = 'Total'
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df.append(df_t), index=['Industry', 'Firm', 'Project'], columns=['Month'], values='Cost', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
df2 = df2.append(df2.sum(axis=0, numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True).fillna('')
df2.iloc[-1, df2.columns.get_loc('Industry')] = 'Total'
df2 = df2.set_index(['Industry', 'Firm', 'Project'])
print(df2.to_string())
```

It will give you the following output.

```
Month                        06-2020  07-2020  08-2020    Total
Industry Firm      Project                                     
Auto     Company1  Alpha      3000.0      0.0      0.0   3000.0
                   NUKDJF     1000.0   5000.0   5000.0  11000.0
Lamps    ASDFInc.  BigThing   2000.0    500.0    500.0   3000.0
         SuperCorp SupProj    1500.0   8000.0   9000.0  18500.0
Total                         7500.0  13500.0  14500.0  35500.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this misses the subtotals per industry and firm.